# Search not returning the question I pasted the query from

Tags: bug, search

This question
[Create a tree object from a temporary index using libgit2 - git2go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246887/create-a-tree-object-from-a-temporary-index-using-libgit2-git2go)
has this text in it (inside of code markup, but still).

`Index is not backed up by an existing repository`

I paste that into the search box and put quotes around it (resulting in [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Index%20is%20not%20backed%20up%20by%20an%20existing%20repository%22)), and there are no results.

That seems wrong to me. I really want to find all instances of people dealing with that error message, which is a not uncommon desire on a programmer Q&A site I would think.

Comment: "is", "not", "by" and "an" are stopwords and removed from a query. It appears that they are removed from a `".."` full phrase search. See the highlighted words in the results for [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Index+is+not+backed+up+by+an+existing+repository+score%3A0+answers%3A1), where those specific words are not highlighted.

Comment: [Hit #2](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22Index+is+not+backed+up+by+an+existing+repository%22), when specifically searching inside code.

Comment: Thanks guys. I don't love that behavior honestly, because I'm searching for an error message which could easily appear either in code or in the text of a question or answer. But I appreciate the answer, and sorry about the duplication.

Comment: Oh wait, I don't love that I specifically have to search within code to find it, but I also don't love that my full phrase search isn't actually doing a full phrase search.